# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown parameter position: 3

Tags: sql, spring, spring-data-jpa, nativequery

jpa nativeQuery

```kotlin

```
@Query(value = 
  "SELECT \"members\".*FROM \"members\" WHERE team_id=?1 AND status=?2 
   ORDER BY CASE WHEN member_id=?3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,last_modified_At asc",
   countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM members where team_id = ?1 AND status =?2",
   nativeQuery = true)
fun findMembers(teamId: Long, status: Short, memberId: Long, pageable: Pageable?): Page<Member>
```

```

the two sql params not all the same when spring boot start get this error. the result is right.how to solve this error?

Comment: can you please post the whole stacktrace

Comment: This is "Spring Data JPA", NOT the JPA API. FYI! And an SQL query needs a space after "*"

Comment: thanks for advice ,but what you answer isn't the heart of this problem

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you use (@Param("teamId") Long teamId) for example?

And then, you will have just to put **:teamId** instead of **?1**.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your count query. It does not use the `?3` parameter.

If you add something like `AND ?3 = ?3` it should fix the problem.

But I'm not sure if this is the best approach.